# Emacs crashes on resize every time starting under X11/GTK3

Tags: gui-emacs, crash

I just built emacs with X11 support on Debian, but every time I start it, the window pops up and works just fine *until I resize the window*, at which point it crashes.

```
user@host:~/emacs-26.1$ ./src/emacs
X protocol error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) on protocol request 130
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.
Fatal error 6: Aborted
Backtrace:
./src/emacs[0x506845]
./src/emacs[0x4ecc04]
./src/emacs[0x5068d3]
./src/emacs[0x4bb663]
./src/emacs[0x4bf0a7]
./src/emacs[0x4bf12b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XError+0x11d)[0x7f5b89a4522d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x42157)[0x7f5b89a42157]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x42215)[0x7f5b89a42215]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XReply+0x238)[0x7f5b89a43128]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XQueryPointer+0x8e)[0x7f5b89a392be]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x584ea)[0x7f5b8b8d84ea]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x77045)[0x7f5b8b8f7045]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(gdk_window_get_device_position_double+0x10b)[0x7f5b8b8ca6eb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(gdk_window_get_device_position+0x2d)[0x7f5b8b8ca7ed]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x33c299)[0x7f5b8bebc299]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x33c7ff)[0x7f5b8bebc7ff]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0(+0x2b6e8)[0x7f5b8b8ab6e8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x4b123)[0x7f5b8a1bb123]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x15a)[0x7f5b8a1ba6aa]
./src/emacs[0x5d7d18]
./src/emacs[0x5a64bd]
./src/emacs[0x41e703]
./src/emacs[0x4f8e3b]
./src/emacs[0x4f9cb4]
./src/emacs[0x4fb784]
./src/emacs[0x56006e]
./src/emacs[0x4ecff4]
./src/emacs[0x56000c]
./src/emacs[0x4ecfb0]
./src/emacs[0x4f1f53]
./src/emacs[0x4f22ab]
./src/emacs[0x414cf3]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f5b86ed02e1]
./src/emacs[0x415a7a]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The [GTK bug mentioned in the dump](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715) is a very old bug (opened in 2002) that was resolved as obsolete within the past few months.

Is this possibly an issue with my configuration or is this a bug I should report to emacs-devel/GTK?

Comment: It also happens when I start emacs maximized (`emacs -mm`) or seemingly any type of sizing.

Comment: Is your entire system up to date? Try doing a full upgrade and starting emacs with no init file (`-q`). This sounds like an ABI conflict to me.

Comment: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` doesn't install any new versions. I don't have an init file yet on this system, but adding `-q` indeed has no impact.

Comment: What drivers do you have for your graphics card? Did you encounter anything similar with any other gtk3 software?

Comment: Recompile Emacs with debug symbols (`CFLAGS=-g ./configure`), launch it within gdb, enable logging backtraces to file and submit a bug report with that backtrace.

Comment: Gotta go home now; I'll recompile tomorrow -- but I did install gedit and it seems to work 'fine' except for some unrelated weirdness that I think is caused by xming.

Comment: I don't think it's actually related to your current crash, but as far as I know, the GTK bug mentioned is not really resolved, it just migrated to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=32518 to the emacs maintainers.

---

From that bug report, there seems to be a patch available that may fix this issue, but that patch is not yet present in Debian-stretch.